# Show rep at time of post

Tags: feature-request, reputation

On the Stack Exchange, I often come across questions/answers by very high rep users that seem to be of very low quality. I am often very surprised, until I realize that they were probably some sort of a new user. My feature proposal is to have a little section in the usercard that would show the rep that the user had at the time of their post. It could be called RAP (rep at post).

[image]

It would be good not only for statistical data, but it would also be really interesting to see how people have improved (or not improved) on asking/answering from their time on SE. It would also make it easier to find a person's first post.

Comment: You can already sort their posts by time posted. Their first post should be their oldest.